# Any way for Doctrine HYDRATE_ARRAY to preserve data type?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I'm retrieving some data using Doctrine 1.2 ORM from a database on a symfony 1.4 project. Currently using a simple query and returning with:

Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY

Is there any way to preserve data types using this method? All data types are cast to a string instead of maintaining a respective int, float, etc based on the database column type...

I would assume that doctrine would be developed enough at this point to maintain data type integrity when appropriate.

Comment: I use HYDRATE_ARRAY lots, never even come across this issue to notice it. Can you provide more information about the context where you're having problems with this?

Comment: If you check the data type of the data returned in the array, each one is cast as a string, rather than the coresponding data type of the column. Ex, an int, smallint, etc. column should be cast as an int and not a string. Same thing for float, decimal, double, should be cast as a float in the array.

Comment: mysql returns strings to php, you can attempt to cast all the strings to objects/datatypes but I think that isn't necessary. E.g. for int, it would automatically be used as an int whenever you do a integer operation on it. Is there some reason for requiring a datatype?

Answer (score 0):

From [Doctrine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/working-with-models):

> You should always use array hydration when you only need to data for access-only purposes, whereas you should use the record hydration when you need to change the fetched data.

So the next text I will put is NOT a good idea, but could answer your question.

Doctrine gives you the [serialize or  unserialize](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/component-overview%3arecord%3aserializing) (YOU SHOULD USE THIS, SEE EXAMPLE) to get the objects. for example, you fetch an array of users, for each one you could run :

```
$user = unserialize($string);
```

where string is the serialized object or equally one of the elements of the fecthArray() result